# How can I get argument values for a given lambda from the outside, without explicitly returning its `binding`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to be able to run a lambda and get at its argument values (the values of `a` and `b` below).

I can achieve this by explicitly having the lambda return a `binding`, and then getting the values out of this binding:

```
fun = lambda { |a, b = Time.now| binding }
fun_binding = fun.call(123)
puts "A is #{fun_binding.local_variable_get(:a)} and B is #{fun_binding.local_variable_get(:b)}"
# Outputs e.g.: A is 123 and B is 2022-04-29 20:14:07 +0200
```

Is it possible to get these values without running any code inside the lambda body? I.e. could I do

```
fun = lambda { |a, b = Time.now| }
fun.call(123)
```

and still get the `a` and `b` values somehow from outside the lambda?

(To provide context – I'm asking because I've [experimented](https://gist.github.com/henrik/ebc0e3a154ceddf150c1867b00c862d6) with this as a shortcut syntax for instantiating objects with ivars/readers automatically assigned. At this stage I'm more curious about what's possible than what is advisable – so I invite any solutions, advisable or not…)

Comment: Re: "Is it possible to get these values without running any code inside the lambda body?" The `Time.now` value of `b` is scoped to the lambda's *stack frame*. It goes out of scope when the lambda exits (unless you return it or the `binding`, as you've shown). In a single-threaded process, you might get the value of `b` by diffing the `ObjectSpace` before and after the `call`. You would have to stop the garbage collector to make the result deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how advisable this is, but you can use the [`TracePoint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/TracePoint.html) class with the `:b_call` event to grab the lambda's binding:

```
fun = lambda { |a, b = Time.now| }

fun_binding = nil
TracePoint.trace(:b_call) do |tp|
    fun_binding = tp.binding
    tp.disable
end

fun.call(123)

puts "A is #{fun_binding.local_variable_get(:a)} and B is #{fun_binding.local_variable_get(:b)}"
```

This is not a perfect solution and will fail if one of the argument default values enters a block on it's own (since the default values are evaluated before the `:b_call` event is fired for the lambda), but that could be fixed with some additional filtering inside the TracePoint handler.

Comment: I love it, and agree it's probably not advisable :) Thank you!